# Why looping through pandas DataFrameGroupBy object stopped halfway

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to parallelize app operation for DataFrameGroupBy, so I wrote code like below

```
keys, grps = [], []
for k, g in tqdm(df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])):
    keys.append(k)
    grps.append(g)
```

and then grps will be sent to a `multiprocessing.Pool`. What I observed is that the looping stopped about 71% of the way and break.

```
71%|███████▏  | 185000/260000 [00:25<00:10, 7353.74it/s]
```

`col1` is a column of string, while the `col2` is a float64. I thought somehow it's the col2 that's causing the problem because `df.groupby(['col1']` would loop through all 260k groups, but I don't know why and how.

pandas version used: 0.23.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dataframe columns contain NaN (missing) values. Make use of **fillna()** function to fill missing values with some default data.

```
for column in df:
    df[column]=df[column].fillna(0)
```

use above code before groupby statement.